# am trying to create a foregin key between trainees table 'identity" field and "trainee_identity" field in bookings table , using laravel 8

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration, laravel-8

The trainees table :

```
    Schema::create('trainees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('telephone');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->integer('identity')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The booking table :

```
    Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
        $table->integer('trainee_identity')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('trainee_identity')->references('identity')->on('trainees');
        $table->string('payed')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Getting this error when migrating:

[image]

***SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'trainee_identity' and referenced column 'identity' in foreign key constraint 'bookings_trainee_identity_
foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `bookings` add constraint `bookings_trainee_identity_foreign` foreign key (`trainee_identity`) references `trainees` (
`identity`))***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference a signed integer in an unsigned integer.
In the `trainees` table `$table->integer('identity')->unique();` is signed, and in the `bookings` table  `$table->integer('trainee_identity')->unsigned();` is unsigned.
Both should be the same type to make it works.
You can change `$table->integer('identity')->unique();` to `$table->unsignedInteger('identity')->unique();` to make it also unsigned